# Using Dojo Grid with REST (tastypie)

Tags: django, json, rest, dojo, tastypie

I am experimenting with Dojo, using a DataGrid/JsonRestStore against a REST-service implemented using Django/tastypie.

It seems that the JsonRestStore expects the data to arrive as a pure array, whilst tastypie returns the dataset within a structure containing "schema" and "objects".

```
{
  "meta": {"limit": 20, "next": null, "offset": 0, "previous": null, "total_count": 1}, 
  "objects": [{...}]
}
```

So, what I need is to somehow attach to the "objects" part.

What is the most sensible way to achieve this ?

- Oyvind

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but you might try creating a custom store that inherits from JsonRestStore and override the internal `_processResults` method.  It's a two-liner in the Dojo 1.7 code base, so you can implement you own behavior quite simply.

```
_processResults: function(results, deferred){
    var count = results.objects.length;
    return {totalCount: deferred.fullLength || (deferred.request.count == count ? (deferred.request.start || 0) + count * 2 : count), items: results.objects};
}
```

See lines 414-417 of the dojox/data/JsonRestStore.js for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this will helpful for you or not. http://jayapal-d.blogspot.in/2009/08/dojo-datagrid-with-editable-cells-in.html